# SQL Server: inserting a complex select query where one field is distinct

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to select values from multiple tables and insert them into another one. One of these values should be distinct. How do I do this with CTE?

My query:

```
insert into Cycle (CycleID, PlotID, Product, Variety, Start, End)
Select CycleID, o.ID, 'Product', v.ID, t.Start, t.End
from 
Import as t 
inner join Varieties as v
on t.Name like v.Name
inner join Plots as o
on t.PlotCode like o.PlotCode
```

I have to make this select only entries where t.CycleID is distinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible SQL trick is to use a `top 1 with ties` in combination with an `order by row_number`

```
insert into Cycle (CycleID, PlotID, Product, Variety, Start, End)
Select top 1 with ties CycleID, o.ID, 'Product', v.ID, t.Start, t.End
from Import as t 
inner join Varieties as v on t.Name like v.Name
inner join Plots as o on t.PlotCode like o.PlotCode
order by row_number() over (partition by CycleID order by o.ID desc, v.ID desc, t.Start desc, t.End desc)
```

*disclaimer : only tested in notepad*

Comment: @BorisK Btw, do you really need to use LIKE in those joins?  Unless it's intentional and v.Name and o.PlotCode have strings with `%` or `_` (f.e. "x%y%1_2"), then using `=` could have the query optimizer come up with a faster execution plan.

Comment: Ah, sure. i'm working with very small datasets, a few hundred records, but will keep in mind for later use.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE AS (

Select DISTINCT  CycleID, o.ID, 'Product', v.ID, t.Start, t.[End]
from 
Import as t 
inner join Varieties as v
on t.Name like v.Name
inner join Plots as o
on t.PlotCode like o.PlotCode )

insert into Cycle 
(CycleID, PlotID, Product, Variety, Start, [End] ) 
Select CycleID, PlotID, Product, Variety, Start, [End] from  CTE 
GROUP BY CycleID, PlotID, Product, Variety, Start, End
```